# Average column in matrix report

Tags: reporting, formula

I'm trying to create report no 7 in the link below (Opportunity Conversion Ratio report)
http://www.dmzinteractive.com/blog/10-must-have-sales-management-reports-your-salesforcecom-dashboard

I'm stuck at adding the average column for Close Rate in my matrix report, it's showing grand total now and I have been trying for hours. Can it be done by using report builder ?
Thanks and appreciate for your time and help.

Comment: You can drop formula fields into your report (at the top of the list of fields that you can add). I don't have time now to check, but if I remember correctly you should be able to use that.

Comment: Thanks @Lex , do you remember how the average formula look like ? How do I calculate Sum of entire row divide by No of columns ?

Comment: At the moment unfortunately I can't. Maybe this weekend I'll take the time to look at the document and try to see if I can figure it out.